# rails jQuery mobile application submitting forms and gets twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile

I am building rails 4 jQuery mobile application but I find that many times, not all, forms are being submitted twice, resulting in double insertion of records. Both in development and production.

I have tried removing UJS and turbolinks but doesn't make any difference. If I disable ajax, my application won't apply the jQuery css to the returned view unless the browser is refreshed.

My javascript files are not being called twice and no assets are installed in public/assets. I have not precompiled any assets.

I wonder if this could be a problem of using a mouse instead of touch screen on a mobile? The application, while only using JQM needs to be usable from a desktop browser as well.

The issue appears to be related to using the same web actions repeatedly, for example, adding sale items to a bill or selecting a submenu item after a menu item in separate web actions.

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require clubapp
//= require jquery.mobile
//= require turbolinks
```

gem file

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.0.rc2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery_mobile_rails'
```

Comment: UJS, jQuery mobile and Turbolinks have lots of overlapped functionalities. I suggest you to give up some of them.

Comment: Can I remove UJS and keep just jQuery Mobile? I don't use UJS but thought mobile might depend on it?

Comment: Yes, you can. jQuery mobile(JM) doesn't depend on UJS. UJS mainly handle form submission and a bit more. JM also manipulates form submission. JM handles page transition, Turbolinks is mainly for that.

Comment: I removed turbolinks but no difference, then I removed UJS but now my delete confirmation js will not work.

Comment: I am using the jquery_mobile_rails gem. Would I be better using the jQuery mobile files directly?

Comment: I don't think that ajax is being disabled. Remove `.ready` it's not recommended for jquery mobile. Also, global settings should be loaded after jquery and before jquery mobile.

Comment: The above javascript, even with .ready removed, prevents my views from being displayed at all. I have read that this relates to development only where assets are loaded twice. If that's not the problem then jQuery mobile and rails seem incompatible.

Comment: Can you check the request doing when you submit you form? I guess that jQuery mobile and the normal request is done. Also you can only response only to ajax request into controller for this specific action. Let me know if something of this helps you

Comment: I assume you mean to try to block ajax response in the controller? If I try unless request.xhr? I just get a nil class error on my collection.

Comment: This appears not to be happening in production so I can put up with it in development.

Comment: I want to rescind the last comment, it is happening in production as well. Form posts are firing twice.

Comment: If I set ajax = false globally, my pages don't load unless I hit refresh, This is so frustrating. I have googled this for 3 days solid now without a result.

Comment: I edited the question to ask about additional layouts being inserted into the DOM by JQM.

Comment: button `click` to submit and `submit` event have the same function?

Comment: I use no custom javascript at all.

Comment: Have you tried during off the ajax submission? And see if that stops it? Have you looked at all the events bound to your form and submit button to make sure something else isn't adding a onsubmit event or onclick?

Comment: Even when i set data-ajax to false it will still fire a second request or submit on occasion. One instance is a link with a parameter and the other is a form. The two are in sequence for selecting an item to add to a bill. There is absolutely nil javascript involved outside jQuery

Comment: @markhorrocks: I remember running into similar issues, pulling out a lot of hair and eventually setting on not using submit buttons. Main reason is JQM submits forms via ajax anyway, so I ended up just using plain button elements and triggering ajax by hand. Let me know if you need the code to set up a global ajax-form-submitter with JQM

Comment: @frequent, thank you. I would appreciate that.

Comment: To whom shall I grant the bounty? :/

Comment: To RDX although none of the answers comes close as nobody even acknowledges seeing the problem which is most odd. I have no listeners at all it should affect everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I went with Twitter Bootstrap instead of jQuery Mobile so I can't say this answer is definitive however its worth making a few comments to help others.

1. Both Turbolinks and jQuery Mobile fire off an ajax call and do a DOM insertion so it would seem that these libraries are incompatible. jQuery mobile probably incorporates Turbolinks anyway.
2. After I noticed that my $(Document).ready javascripts would not work unless the page was refreshed I found this gem which fixed that problem.

   gem 'jquery-turbolinks'

I suspect that the combination of the above might fix this problem. One outstanding issue was that JQM seemed to cache pages which had been updated despite the default apparently being not to do so. Explicitly switching off this behaviour did not help.

Answer (score 3):

It could be that some of your Javascript listeners are getting attached twice. For example, let's say you have the following sale item element:

```
<div class="sale-item">
  <!-- inputs -->
  <button class="add">Add Sale Item</button>
</div>
```

And you have a dynamic list of sale items that you keep on appending dynamically via javascript. But at each addition, you do the following code:

```
// When adding a new sale item:
    $(".sale-item .add").click(function() {
      // ajax request
    });
```

So whenever you add a new sale item, a listener is created for `$(".sale-item .add")`, which actually includes all submit items in the page. Then what happens is:

- **1st Time:** `Sale Item 1` added, listener set
- **2nd Time:** `Sale Item 2` added, listener added for both `Sale Item 1` *and* `Sale Item 2`. So now `Sale Item 1` has two listeners, which will cause duplicate submits

[Here is a demonstration](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IEiLy).

#### Confirming if there are duplicate listeners:

Once you're able to reproduce the bug, note the ID or class of the button that triggers the double-submit. Then in the Chrome/Firefox console/firebug, run:

```
$("<element that's triggering double-submits>").data("events")
> Object {click: Array[1]}
```

If it shows `click: Array[1]`, then you have only one click listener, and nothing is wrong with your code. If it shows `click: Array[2]` or more, then its a code issue, you're somehow having double listeners.

#### Causes for Double-listeners

- You have multiple events where the same listener is getting added (i.e. the above-said example)
- You have two different buttons using the same/similar class (say one button has class `"btn submit"` and another has class as just `"submit"`). So the listener that you add by saying `$(".submit")` now gets added to both `"btn submit"` and `"submit"` buttons!

Finding the place where the duplicates are present is quite difficult, you'll have to do it manually by checking your code carefully.

Comment: I have no custom javascript code written by me. The issue is intermittent and seems to start when actions are repeated many times.

Comment: I run into the double listener issue all the time. I just throw in a jQuery.stopImmediatePropagation on the event and if the double submits go away, I start searching for the non-intentional listener.

Comment: Could this be the problem? I don't know enough to figure this out. The main worry seems to be submitting a form with method get https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/commit/92b813f902b18971473e9791be49c75da1dd17d0

Answer (score 2):

I also had problems with a JQM form submission (mostly trying to prevent it). Eventually I replaced my form submit buttons with plain `<input>`

A button will call a handler:

```
<input type="button" class="fake_submit" onclick="my_handler()" data-role="button" data-theme="e" data-icon="arrow-r" />
```

The `handler` will get the form contents, modify what is needed and call my global `submitter`:

My handler will be something like this (you could also `on('click', '.fake_submit', function...`)

```
myHandler = function () {
    // get the form
    var form = $(this).closest('form'),
        // custom parameter, I'm creating to route on server side
        switcher = form.find('input[name="form_submitted"]').val(),
        // which url to call
        urlToCall= "../services/form_xyz.cfc",
        // custom parameter, which method to call server-side
        method = "process",
        // override default GET
        type = "post",
        // we expect JSON
        returnformat = "JSON",
        // in case we want to changePage when we have the result
        targetUrl = "",
        // serialize the form and attach custom parameters
        formdata = form.serialize()+"&method="+method+"&returnformat="+returnformat,
        // run this function on success
        successHandler = function() {
            // for example
            switch (switcher) {
                case "login":
                    // refersh application to prevent backbutton
                    window.location = 'index.html';
                    break;
                case "logout":
                    window.location = 'login.html';
                    break;
                case "forget":
                    $.mobile.changePage('lost.html', {transition: 'fade' });
                    break;
                case "message_sent":
                    $.mobile.changePage( 'thanks.html', {transition: 'pop', role: "dialog" });
                    break;
                }
            };
    // call the global ajaxhandler  
    ajaxFormSubmit( form, urlToCall, formdata, targetUrl, successHandler, null, "", returnformat, type );
    // for good measure (and because I also started to be paranoid about awol-submits...
    return false;
    });
};
```

And the submitter:

```
var ajaxFormSubmit = 
    function ( 
        form,
        urlToCall,
        formdata,       // serialized form data
        targetUrl,      // I think I'm not using this at all... 
        successHandler, //
        dataHandler,    // true/false > does the success function require the response sent back
        errorHandler,   // function to be run on server-side errors
        returnformat,
        type            // override default GET if needed
        ){

            $.ajax({
              async: false,
              type: type == "" ? "get" : type,
              url: urlToCall,
              data: formdata,
              dataType: returnformat,
              success: function( objResponse ){
                 // I'm passing back string or object from the server
                 if (objResponse.SUCCESS == true || typeof objResponse == "string" ){
                    // we need the data returned to continue?
                    dataHandler ? successHandler( objResponse ) : successHandler();
             } else {
                    // server side error
                    if ( errorHandler !== "" ){
                        errorHandler();
                    }
                }
            },
            // ajax error  
            error: function (jqXHR, XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                console.log(error); 
            }
        });
    }
```

I did a fairly complex application and I'm doing all form submits this way. Works without errors. Let me know if you have any questions regarding the above.

Comment: My application has over a hundred web actions and the problem relates to both links and forms, although with forms I see it only with method = get. It seems intermittent and doesn't only affect the same actions. I need a solution as to why this is occurring, rather than a hack to "fix" it.

Comment: It also seems that when it happens the following action will also be double fired.